# Dynamically filter swift command line input

Tags: swift, command-line, swift3

I'm trying to create a command line app using Swift Package Manager which get some data from user and make something with it. Sounds simple, huh?

```
func handleInput() {
    if let username = requestEnterUserName(), !username.isEmpty {
        print("You entered valid username: \(username)")
    } else {
        handleInput()
    }
}

func requestUserName() -> String? {
    print("Please enter username: ", terminator: "")
    let username = readLine()
    let trimmedUserName = username.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    return trimmedUserName
}
```

My problem is that I don't need backspace characters in username, or whitespace in the middle of it. I would like to filter it dynamically. To delete wrong character after user wrote it. I wonder if it is possible at all.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Do you want to filter the input *while the user is typing?*

Comment: @MartinR, yes, if it is possible.